# When do intent extras become null between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm having problems receiving intent extras between activities.

In my MainActivity I start a Gallery activity to chose video files on external SD card:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
    //Button change video
    Button video_change;
    //Extra for changing video content
    Bundle extras;
    //Intent for Gallery view activity
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //...
     intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GalleryView.class);

     video_change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                      Uri mUri = null;
                      try {
                          Field mUriField = VideoView.class.getDeclaredField("mUri");
                          mUriField.setAccessible(true);
                          mUri = (Uri) mUriField.get(myVideoView);          
                      } catch(Exception e) {
                          //TODO: Something here
                      }
                      String string = mUri.toString();
                      intent.putExtra("old_video",string);
                      startActivity(intent);            
                  }
              });
      }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Config.DEBUG)
            Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "+ ON RESUME +");
        try {
            extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null){
                Log.d("++ ON RESUME ++","Found Extra!");
                String newvideo = extras.getString("new_video");
                Log.d("++ ON RESUME ++","NEW VIDEO: "+ newvideo);
                Uri tempuri = Uri.parse(newvideo);
                myVideoView.setVideoURI(tempuri);         
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
  }
```

Then in my GalleryView activity:

```
public class GalleryView extends Activity {

    ImageView back_button;
    ListView videolist;
    List<String> videos = new ArrayList<String>();
    private File[] videoFiles;
    //private Cursor videocursor;
    //private int video_column_index;
    int x=0;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
         back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
         videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

         start_listview();

         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_listview,videos);
         videolist.setAdapter(adapter);

         videolist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {
                    String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                    Log.d("VALUE: ",value);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
                    // Send the file path
                    i.putExtra("new_video", value);
                    startActivity(i);
              }
         });

         back_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           //videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           //videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                String newString = extras.getString("old_video");
                intent.putExtra("new_video", newString);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
         });
     }

    public void start_listview() {

        String path = ("/storage/extsd/Videos/");
        File directory = new File(path);
        videoFiles = directory.listFiles();
        try {
            for (File f : videoFiles) {
                Log.d("FILE: ", f.toString());
                String file = f.toString();
                Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                videos.add(file);
            }
            //Set the visibility of the progress bar to false.
            findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I when I return back to the MainMenu activity, I the extra is found, but is null! From logcat:

```
MainMenu           + ON RESUME +
++ ON RESUME ++    Found Extra!
++ ON RESUME ++    NEWVIDEO: null
```

Even if I put the `extras = intent.getExtras()` call in the onCreate, it never gets called because it never passes the `extras != null` check

---

**HOW I FIXED IT (THANKS TO STEFAN'S ANSWER)**

So my MAIN problem was that my Main Activity was always being set to the background whenever I started the new Gallery Activity. My manifest file dictated that it would do a `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on the Main Activity. So, somehow when the Main Activity was re-started, the intent was never truly passed since the app was always running in the background and never passed the intent extras. So I tried the onNewIntent() method call and tried the piece of code in there to receive the extras, and it worked! Thanks again to Stefan!

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult` and retrieve the values `onActivityResult` https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: I tried this once. I will try again

Comment: Same result as before, It found the extra, but the string is null.

Comment: If all you want to do is reference it later in the same class why don't you just store it in a class member variable?

Comment: I don't really think that would make a difference, no? I made the intent, extra, and newvideo string public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is to call the `MainActivity` again after opening the gallery. Depending on the flags used in your manifest, that might cause that your main activity is not launched a second tim, but that your initial main activity is unpaused and raised to foreground.

If this is the case, due to the activity lifecycle, `onCreate(...)`will not be called again, **but** you can check if the following method is called:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //TODO: check here if your intent extras arrive and log, then debug
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes. I do see in my manifest, I have the activity set to `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. I will try to see how onNewIntent works.

Comment: Placed logs inside OnNewIntent, but it never gets called.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using your method! I changed from doing it by onActivityResult in MainMenu, and `setResult();` in the Gallery Activity and just used the onNewIntent method instead by adding extras and using `startActivity(intent);`